# Extra detail in Atiyah and Macdonald Ex 5.8 on integral dependence

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $f$, $g$, $h$ monic polynomials in $A[x]$ ( $A$ a commutative ring with $1$)  $f\cdot g = h$, $\deg h = n$, $\deg f = k$, $\deg g = n-k$.  Show that every coefficient of $f$ satisfies a monic integral equation of degree $\binom{n}{k}$ whose coefficients  are polynomial expressions in the coefficients of $h$ ( with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$)

Note:

1. This is (essentially) the statement of ex 5.8 in Atiyah-Macdonald.  The only  extra is the fact that the degree is $\binom{n}{k}$.
2. Found  by obtaining explicit dependencies in particular cases (using Groebner bases)  and noticing the degree.
3. Posted as [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Any feedback would be appreciated!